# Source code in browser window

Tags: laravel, bootstrapping

My friend is working with laravel and trying to run her code, but she is getting the source code in her browser window, and the navigation bar at the top is also not visible, instead Toggle navigation is written and a small button is there. 
What could possibly the reason behind it?

Answer (score 0):

An image would help us solve the problem

What environment are you both running on?

Are you using a Version Control Software? If so, which.

Did you run Composer Install when you cloned the project?

Comment: Which question are you answering?

Comment: I mean, no we are not using version control software, we are not working on the same project, so no cloning. We are working on laravel 5.2, on different projects. And she has installed composer, and other stuff too.

Comment: Her bootstrapp is working fine, individually, but isn't workin gwith laravel.